# Make histogram from data table in R

Tags: r, histogram

I have a variable say a which has data as

```
Count |  Value
2 | Apple
5 | Ball
6 | Cat
10 | Dog
```

I want to construct a histogram such that, I have the values in x-axis and count in y axis. Dont know how to do

Comment: I guess you need a barplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `barplot`

```
barplot(setNames(df1$Count, df1$Value))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Count = c(2, 5, 6, 10), Value = c("Apple", "Ball",  
"Cat", "Dog")), .Names = c("Count", "Value"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```